# A Function that will convert number bases and Errors for illegal inputs

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have written a function that will convert strings between different user specified number bases. For example octal is 8, decimal is 10. Letters A to Z could be considered up to base 26.

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<math.h>
    #define MAXBUF 64

    int baseconv(char s[], int sb, char d[], int db);

    void main()
    {
        char s[MAXBUF+1], d[MAXBUF+1]; // source, destination value (as char string)
        int sb,db;                     // source, destination base
        int decval;                    // calculated decimal value
        char buf[MAXBUF+10];           // temp buffer
        char *p;                       // pointer to string

        printf("Enter src value, src base, dst base: ");
        gets(buf);
        p=strtok(buf," ,");
        while(stricmp(p,"END"))
        {
            strcpy(s,p);
            p=strtok(NULL," ,");        // or sb=atoi(strtok(NULL," ,"))
            sb=atoi(p);

            p=strtok(NULL," ,");        // or db=atoi(strtok(NULL," ,"))
            db=atoi(p);

            decval = baseconv(s,sb,d,db);

            printf("%s|%d = %d|10 = %s|%d\n", s,sb,decval,d,db);
            printf("Enter src value, src base, dst base: ");
            gets(buf);
            p=strtok(buf," , ");
        }
    }

    // actual baseconv() function 

    int baseconv(char s[], int sb, char d[], int db)
    {
        char t1[MAXBUF+10];
        char t[MAXBUF+10];
        int v=0,i=0,j=0,temp,k=0;
        while(s[i]) 
        {
            if(s[i]>=48 && s[i] < 58)    
                v = v * sb + (s[i]-48);    
            else if(s[i]>=65 && s[i]<71) 
                v = v * sb + (s[i]-65)+10;  
            else if(s[i]>=97 && s[i]<103) 
                v = v * sb + (s[i]-97)+10;
            i++;   
        }
        temp=v;
        while(v)
        {
            if(v%db+48 >= 48 && v%db+48 < 58)   
                t[j] =(v%db)+48;
            else if(v%db+55 >=65)            
                t[j] =(v%db)+55;       
            else if(v%db+87 >=97)      
                t[j] =(v%db)+87;
            v = v/db; 
            j++;
        }

        for(int n=j-1;n>=0;n--) 
        {
            t1[k]=t[n]; 
            k++;
        }
        t1[j]='\0';
        strcpy(d,t1);  
        return temp;
    }
```

Output is like this-

```
Enter source value, source base, dest base: 1234, 8, 16
1234|8 = 668|10 = 29C|16"
```

And

```
Enter source value, source base, dest base: face, 16, 8
face|16 = 64206|10 = 175316|8"
```

However, I cannot get it to specify if the source value is illegal for the specified source base (for example 1234|3, return -1, and place the value "ERROR" in d[].

Output WOULD be like this-

```
Enter source value, source base, dest base: 12345, 5, 10
12345|5 = -1|10 = ERROR|10"
```

How would I implement the return -1 and ERROR?

Comment: at a high level: while iterating through the nunber, check if a digit is too high. Then return early with the desired error values.

Comment: I would be tempted to use less code and more lookup tables. 35 lookup strings that directly convert an input char in the addressed base to either its binary value, or -1 if illegal in that base.

Comment: @MartinJames: On faster embedded systems such tables can slow down your code significantly.

Comment: @Olaf I would not be surprised by that.  OTOH, a table-driven converter is more likely to .. work correctly.

Comment: Why would you want it to report "-1" for base 10, but "ERROR" for the user-specified base? -1 is a legitimate output value for the input string "-1".  The easiest way to report an error is to add another argument to the function:

Comment: For typical applications, the base is a constant, so an assertion (or a run-time failure) should be sufficient. A unit-test can easily ensure correct calls.

Comment: Side comment: You can make your code easier to write, easier to read, *and* more portable (triple win!) by replacing e.g. 48 with `'0'`, 65 with `'A'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that maps a character to its ordinal value for a given base.

```
int map_digit_to_ordinal (int x) {
    static int map[MAX_CHAR];
    const char *digits = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const char *p;
    if (x < 0 || x >= MAX_CAR) return -1;
    if (map['1'] == 0) {
        for (p = digits; *p; ++p) {
            map[*p] = 1 + p - digits;
            map[toupper(*p)] = 1 + p - digits;
        }
    }
    return map[x] - 1;
}
```

You can have a different function to check if the digit falls within your desired base.

```
int digit_in_base (int digit, int base) {
    if (base > 36) return -1;
    if (digit < base) return digit;
    return -1;
}
```

Then, your conversion function can use this function to map the potential digit to the right value. If the returned value is `-1`, your function should return early, writing `"ERROR"` to the destination.

Now, your conversion function loop can make the appropriate checks.

```
while(s[i]) {
    temp = map_digit_to_ordinal(s[i]);
    temp = digit_in_base(temp, sb);
    if (temp == -1) {
        strcpy(d, "ERROR");
        return -1;
    }
    v = v * sb + temp;
    i++;
}
/* rest of function ... */
```